# How to switch between hosts on glab CLI

Tags: gitlab

When using glab (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/), is there a way to pass a "--host" parameter to specify which host to use based on entries in the config.yml file?  My config.yml file looks [partially] like this:

```
# configuration specific for gitlab instances
hosts:
    hostA:
        # What protocol to use to access the api endpoint. Supported values: http, https
        api_protocol: https
        # Configure host for api endpoint, defaults to the host itself
        api_host: host_a_url.com
        # Your GitLab access token. Get an access token at https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens
        token: <token_value>
    gitlab:
        api_protocol: https
        api_host: gitlab_example.com
        token: <token_value>
# Default GitLab hostname to use
host: hostA
```

When on the command line, I would expect the command to look something like

```
glab repo clone --host gitlab -g <group_id> -p --paginate
```

but I can't seem to find if a parameter exists like "--host" to allow me to switch between the hosts identified in the config.yml file for running individual commands.

Answer (score 0):

Using `glab config` command, you can configure this. You will need to set the following parameters:

**NOTE**: Change any values you see inside `< >` with values that are relevant to your scenario.

```
glab config set api_host <my.gitlab-domain.com> -g -h <my.gitlab-domain.com>
glab config set api_protocol https -g -h <my.gitlab-domain.com>
glab config set git_protocol <https/ssh> -g -h <my.gitlab-domain.com>
```

### Example

```
glab config set api_host my.gitlab-domain.com -g -h my.gitlab-domain.com
glab config set api_protocol https -g -h my.gitlab-domain.com
glab config set git_protocol ssh -g -h my.gitlab-domain.com
```

- api_host will configure GitLab CLI to connect to use the specified domain such as my.gitlab-domain.com for any repo that contains that domain (ie: my.gitlab-domain.com/myrepo)
- api_protocol specifies what protocol GitLab CLI should use to talk to GitLab server's backend
- git_protocol will configure what protocol git should use to clone the repository (https or SSH)
- -g option will write these configurations under ~/config/.gitlab-cli/config.yml

My understanding is GitLab CLI uses git under the hood to clone repositories for you.

Alternatively you can set the following environment variables to do so:

- GITLAB_HOST
- GITLAB_API_HOST